# For replacement in a delayed expansion variable in a batch file

Tags: arrays, windows, batch-file, for-loop

I need to use a loop to  replace a variable (%%g) in variables already assigned in a windows batch file. I tried and it works only if i use %var%, but if i use !var! it doesn't replace the variables and it's a problem because i have these variables in an array and i can only use !var[%%h]! (%var[%%h]% doesn't work).
Is there a way to make it work? maybe with a call to something?

Here's an example:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET var[0]=Hi %%g
SET var[1]=Ciao %%g
SET var[2]=Hola %%g
SET var[3]=Hallo %%g
SET var[4]=Salut %%g
FOR %%g in ( Luke Paul Tom Mark) DO (
    for /L %%h in (0,1,4) do (
    ECHO !var[%%h]!
    )
)
```

Here's what i get:

```
Hi %g
Ciao %g
Hola %g
Hallo %g
Salut %g
Hi %g
Ciao %g
Hola %g
Hallo %g
Salut %g
Hi %g
Ciao %g
Hola %g
Hallo %g
Salut %g
Hi %g
Ciao %g
Hola %g
Hallo %g
Salut %g
```

And here's what i'd like to get:

```
Hi Luke
Ciao Luke
Hola Luke
Hallo Luke
Salut Luke
Hi Paul
Ciao Paul
Hola Paul
Hallo Paul
Salut Paul
Hi Tom
Ciao Tom
Hola Tom
Hallo Tom
Salut Tom
Hi Mark
Ciao Mark
Hola Mark
Hallo Mark
Salut Mark
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
SET var[0]=Hi %%%%g
SET var[1]=Ciao %%%%g
SET var[2]=Hola %%%%g
SET var[3]=Hallo %%%%g
SET var[4]=Salut %%%%g
FOR %%g in ( Luke Paul Tom Mark) DO (
    for /L %%h in (0,1,4) do (
    call :myECHO !var[%%h]!
    )
)
goto :EOF

:myECHO
for %%x in (1) do echo %*
exit /B
```

**EDIT**: *Some explanations added*

Your original program show `%g` in the output because the parsing order of the elements in the `FOR` commands:

- 1- The expansion of the first `FOR` replaceable parameter, from `%%g` to `Luke`, `Paul`, etc.
- 2- The expansion of the second `FOR` replaceable parameter, from `%%h` to `0 1 2 3 4`
- 3- The expansion of `!var[0]!`, `!var[1]!`, etc. by their values: `Hi %g`, `Ciao %g`, etc.

At this moment, the expansion of `%g` was done two steps before, so it is *not* performed again. You may review a more detailed explanation of this expansion order at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2097&p=9425#p9425).

We need to *parse again* the final value of the array elements in order to change `%g` by its current value, and the easiest way to do that is invoking a subroutine. However, when the value of each array element is parsed in the subroutine, the usual processing of percent-signs take place, so it is necessary that the original value of array elements have two times the number of percent signs.

We could pass to the subroutine the current value of `%%g` in a parameter and explicitly replace it in the final value, for example:

```
    call :myECHO "%%g" "!var[%%h]!"
    . . .
    . . .
:myECHO
set "var=%~2"
echo !var:%%g=%~1!
exit /B
```

However, I opted for an interesting trick that may be summarized this way: The replaceable parameters of all *active* `FOR` commands are replaced by their values in the code executed inside the `FOR` commands *even if such code is placed in a separated subroutine*. This way, in order to have access to the original `%%g` replaceable parameter in the subroutine, it is only necessary to activate a `FOR` command. This point is further explained at [this post](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3457&p=17374#p17374).

Comment: I prefer your solution, as it only needs to define the array once. But why you didn't explain it, it's not obvious why it works :-) A long time ago someone criticized me for not explaining my solutions

Comment: Thanks! It's what i was searching. ANd thanks for the explanation. It helped a lot ;)

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%g in (Luke Paul Tom Mark) DO (
SET var[0]=Hi %%g
SET var[1]=Ciao %%g
SET var[2]=Hola %%g
SET var[3]=Hallo %%g
SET var[4]=Salut %%g
    for /L %%h in (0,1,4) do (
    ECHO !var[%%h]!
    )
pause
)
```